# Laravel Eloquent relationship insert/update best pratices

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I've searched a lot about this question but having trouble finding the 'right' answer.
I'm trying to insert/update a db-entry with an automatic update of the relation (as far as i can tell this is not possible in a single call).

So the first question:

- Is this the right approach
- Is it possible to update the related address(record) in the persons->create/save call kind a way..

```
->save([
'persondata',
'address' => [
    'zip' => 'xxxx',
    'nr' => 1
 ]
];
```

### My Current situation

**Database layout:**

table: persons:
id|name

table: addresses:
id|zip|nr|addressable_id|addressable_type

**Models:**

Person:

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Addresses', 'addressable');
}
```

Addresses:

```
public function addressable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**controller**
Person:

```
store()
{
    $validated = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'address.zip' => 'required',
        'address.nr' => 'required'
    ]);
    $person = Person::create($validated);
    $address = new Addresses(request()->input('address'));
    $address->addressable()->associate($person);
    $address->save();
}
update(Person $person)
{
    $validated = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'address.zip' => 'required',
        'address.nr' => 'required'
    ]);
    $person->update($validated);
    $person->address->update(request()->input('address'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much opinion based but I'd do the following:

`php artisan make:request PersonRequest`

```
# app\Http\Request\PersonRequest.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PersonRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        // Note I'm NOT putting zip an nr into an array.
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'zip' => 'required',
            'nr' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
public function store(PersonRequest $request)
{
    $person = Person::create($request->validated());
    $person->address()->create($request->validated());
}

public function update(PersonRequest $request, Person $person)
{
    $person->update($request->validated());
    $person->address()->update($request->validated());
}
```

You'll notice I'm just reusing `validated`. That's because I'm depending on the models fillable attributes and letting those strip away the parts of the validated request I don't need.

```
# Assuming Person's fillable attributes are only 'name'
Person::create(['name' => 'name', 'zip' => 'zip', 'nr' => 'nr'])
# Is the same as Person::create(['name' => 'name']);
```

This solution works best for models that do not share attribute names.

Comment: Hi 
i agree it's opinion based.. To be honest i'm more curious if it's possible to let the person model handle the saving / update of an address. (by default laravel handling). I've looked at the "->push" method however i'm not sure if that's applicable for polymorh relations

Comment: I mean, you could make a method in your `Person` model but remember this will always be translated into two queries in the end. I prefer letting the relationship classes handle it. (In this case, the `MorphOne` class, which in turn ends up deferring to the related model class, `Address`). There is no magic way to insert values into two tables with 1 sql query. At least not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Person Model
public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Person');
    }

// Address Model
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Addresses');
    }

// Controller 
// create function
 public function create()
    {
        $address = Addresse::all();
        return view('admin.post.create',compact('categories));
    }
// store function
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

            $this->validate($request,[
                'name' => 'required',
                'addressable_id' => 'required',
            ]);
            $person             = new Person();
            $person->addressable_id  =$id;
            $person->name      = $request->name;
            $person->save();
            Toastr::success('Your Name Successfully submited','Success');
            return redirect()->back();

    }
```